# ¿Por qué no me desloguea de la aplicación al pasar los minutos?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una aplicación Laravel 5.5 que no se desloguea a pesar de que le tengo puesto un límite de tiempo para la sesión:

```
   <?php

return [

    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 5),

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

La cosa es que aunque tiene un límite corto, este no funciona. No me funciona el deslogueo ni aún cerrando el navegador, no sé que puede ser.

He probado a ponerle un middleware que me sacara de la sesión nada más pasar el tiempo pero me ha dado error y no se como va el middleware en ese caso.

El middleware que creé para que cerrara la sesión, gracias a
 [este post](https://arjunphp.com/laravel5-inactivity-idle-session-logout/)

```
<?php

namespace libreir\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;

class SessionTimeout {

    /**
     * Check session data, if role is not valid logout the request
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        $bag = Session::getMetadataBag();

        $max = config('session.lifetime') * 60; // min to hours conversion

        if (($bag && $max < (time() - $bag->getLastUsed()))) {

            $request->session()->flush(); // remove all the session data

            Auth::logout(); // logout user

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Pero me salía un error porque decía que no tengo la clase session y no se a qué se refiere con eso, puesto que si que tengo un fichero session.php dentro de config. Tampoco sabría cómo crearlo ni a qué se refiere, si a una tabla de la base de datos o a algo interno de Laravel.

También en este sitio hay otro middleware que supuestamente funciona: [Middleware TimeOut](https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/session-timeout-for-logged-in-user) yo lo he probado pero a mi no me ha funcionado tampoco.
También he probado el de esta página:[Middleware TimeOut Dos](https://alfrednutile.info/posts/168)

que es la edición del primero y en el que me salía el error siguiente al añadirlo al kernel.php:

[image: Error del Middleware]

Estoy preguntando después de buscar información, puesto que no he encontrado nada que me solventara el problema. Gracias por su tiempo y atención.

Comment: Normalmente funciona la configuración por defecto, no obstante si quieres que cierre sesión cuando cierre el navegador tienes que poner a true **'expire_on_close' => false,** y revisa en tu archivo **.env** que valor tiene SESSION_LIFETIME ya que de ahí es donde el toma el valor original aunque en tu session.php tengas definido 5

Comment: He hecho eso que me has puesto, pero sigue sin funcionar...¿Tengo acaso que apagar el pc o algo para que se actualicen los datos?

Comment: Jajaja se me habia olvidado cada vez que cambies algo en un archivo de configuración debes ejecutar el comando **artisan config:cache** porque esos datos se cachean y al hacer eso actualizas los cambios en la caché de configuración. ;P

Comment: Muchas gracias Dariel, me ayudó mucho tu comentario, ¿por qué no lo pones de respuesta para que así la gente sepa como se arregla eso?

Comment: OKOK ya la agregué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente funciona la configuración por defecto, no obstante si quieres que cierre sesión cuando cierre el navegador tienes que poner a true 'expire_on_close' => false, y revisa en tu archivo .env que valor tiene SESSION_LIFETIME ya que de ahí es donde el toma el valor original aunque en tu session.php tengas definido 5.

Debes borrar la caché de la configuración con el comando
**artisan config:cache** luego de haber cambiado cualquier dato dentro de los archivos en la carpeta config\

Comment: Lo cierto es que el session_lifetime hace su tarea pero el 'expire_on_close' no, no entiendo el por qué. Y si, he hecho el artisan config:cache.